The generalized Laplace expansion for tensor
I'm reading this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3860.
In the Appendix (page 22), the author uses a generalized Laplace expansion for the determinant tensor, as shown in the picture1.
But I only known about the Laplace expansion for the determinant of a matrix, what is the Laplace expansion for a tensor? I have searched in Google, but got nothing.
My question is: Does this Laplace expansion is right for all the tensor? If so, what is the mathematical formulation of it and are there any references? If not, does it right for any anti-symmetric tensor in $\otimes ^N \mathbb{R}^K$, with $K \ge N$ and what's the formulation of it?

Identifying tensors with multilinear forms on the rows of a matrix, this is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256098/generalized-laplace-expansion-and-algebra-of-alternating-functions or §6.22 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09862v3 .
